# permutation with repetition

Tags: r, permutation

In R, how can I produce all the permutation of a group, but in this group there are some repetitive elements.

Example :

```
A = {1,1,2,2,3}
```

solution :

```
1,1,2,2,3
1,1,2,3,2
1,1,3,2,2
1,2,1,2,3
1,2,2,1,3
1,2,2,3,1
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using the `gtools` package,

```
library(gtools)

x <- c(1,1,2,2,3)

permutations(5, 5, x, set = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `combinat` package:

```
A = c(1,1,2,2,3)
library(combinat)
permn(A)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with built-in R:

```
permute <- function(vec,n=length(vec)) {
  permute.index <- sample.int(length(vec),n)
  return(vec[permute.index])
}

permute(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `permute` package:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,3)
require(permute)
allPerms(x, observed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done extensive research on combination and permutation. This result which I have found is written on a book Known as Junction (an art of counting combination and permutation. To view my site then log on to https://sites.google.com/site/junctionslpresentation/home

I have also have solution for your question. I have also found to order a multiple object permutation. This multiple object permutation I call it (CON of MSNO) which means Combination Order Number of Multiple Same Number of Objects.

To view this method of ordering then go to the site https://sites.google.com/site/junctionslpresentation/proof-for-advance-permutation
at the bottom of this site I have attached some word documents. Your required solution is written on the word document 12 Proof (CON of MSNO) and 13 Proof (Converse of CON of MSNO). Download this word document for the proper view of the written matters.